# js update scroll event continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

May I ask the detail of the giving solution from below question?? I have exactly the same problem.

[jQuery’s css() lags when applied on scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075525/jquerys-css-lags-when-applied-on-scroll-event)

On giving solution #3 ->> If you want continuous updates, keep track of the timestamp when you do an update, and do nothing in the handler if it's been less than some amount of time (100ms or whatever).

Can I have more detailed information how to do or example about it?

Comment: You should have posted in the same thread and added comments. Did you check the answer suggested on the same post.

Comment: Oh, I though that its better to open a new thread..sorry. Yes, I do checked all the answer. And searched a lot online...I havent find a solution yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something similar to this:

```
var lastUpdate = new Date().getTime();
$(selector).scroll(function() {
     var now = new Date().getTime();
     if (now - lastUpdate > 100) {
          // update css
          lastUpdate = now;
     }
 });
```

This will update the css every .1s (which is what I think you would want. Obviously, just replace selector with whatever element you're binding the scroll event to, and replace the update css comment with your .css() call!

Comment: I am not quite understand. But my understanding is that Chrome or IE do not response scrolling so faster than Firefox. If so, the scroll event actually called will not change by this method?? isnt it? Since everything time this function will be called is depends on brower??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Please try to rephrase?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. However, I did try your method and apply it to the example from the question link in my question. It didnt work in the questioner`s example......

Comment: I don't think my method is the best way to go about it, but it certainly answers your question about not performing updates but every 100ms with scroll event.